# ZPL set label size reserve print

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have some information I want to print out with a label size of 600 however I can't seem to get it to print the opposite way.

zpl code

```
! U setvar "ezpl.media_type" "mark"
setvar "zpl.label_length" "600"
END

^XA^LH110,10^FWR
^FO400,0^ASR,18,10^FDInformation^FS
^FO350,0^ASR,18,10^FD Instructions:^FS
^FO350,200^ASR,18,10^FD [instructions] ^FS
^FO250,0^ASR,18,10^FD address:^FS
^FO200,0^ASR,18,10^FD [address]^FS
^FO150,0^ASR,18,10^FD [street]^FS
^FO100,0^ASR,18,10^FD [city]^FS
^XZ
```

the issue I am having is it prints like.
"space" instructions : do this inste
and cuts it off after a few words. I can't seem to do negative x axis values to just force it to start at the beginning.

So is there a way to make it print in reserve? 
so its
"way less space now" .xob siht htiw daetsni siht od : snoitcurtsni

Answer (score 1):

Use `^LL` to sent the Label Length. You are not setting that in the ZPL that you show as your example. You can see the Zebra ZPL Programming guide to see details on how to use the command. If you want 600 pixels long, then this should be your first line of ZPL:

```
^XA^LH110,10^LL600^FWR
```

Comment: ! U setvar "ezpl.media_type" "mark"
setvar "zpl.label_length" "600"
END is doing length of 600

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that. Try changing to the ZPL command as stated to see if that works.

Comment: @EdHayes3 Using ^LL, ^LS or ^PW doesn't do anything. In my case it always has a half inch (100 dot) margin on the left side (from my perspective when it prints out) of the label. Tried going into the driver/preferences and setting the label size there. Still does nothing.

Comment: You might need to calibrate the printer for your media. Sometimes the sensor for the calibration comes loose too, so that may need to be investigated. Else, if you still have problems, try posting a new question with some images of what you expect, and what you are actually getting, along with he code you are using.